# Inherit Grails Domain Class properties from a base Class

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-domain-class

Im trying to create a Domain Class Constructor that inherits another class properties dynamically. But I cannot get it to work properly.

Heres an example:

```
class Example1 {

  String name;
  String location;
}

class Example2 extends Example1 {

  String status;

  public Example2 (Example1 orig){
    // Code here to set this.name and this.location  to name and location from orig
    // dynamically, so adding a field in Example1 does not require me to add that 
    // field here.
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried, it says I have to wait 8 hrs :(

Comment: Yeah, there's a time limit. Maybe come back tomorrow and do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enough troubleshooting and searching online I found a solution, here it is in case anyone is ever looking for something similar:

```
public Example2(Example1 orig){
   def d = new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(Example1.class)
   d.persistentProperties.each { val ->
       this[val.name] = orig[val.name]         
   }       
}
```

Include this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass
```

Answer (score 2):

You're working too hard, just copy the properties:

```
class Example2 extends Example1 {

   String status

   Example2() {}

   Example2(Example1 orig) {
      this.properties = orig.properties
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what it is that you want to accomplish, but is there any reason that you can't just have an "Example1" field in the "Example2" class?

Comment: I did not want to duplicate data across multiple classes, sorta defeats the purpose of extending. I came up with a solution, it is posted above.

Comment: or just make Example1 abstract (stick in src/groovy if Example1's props are all you need); extend Example2 from it and move on.